# boost::dynamic_bitset inconsistent result with std::vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, stdvector, boost-dynamic-bitset

I look up the boost's implementation of the `dynamic_bitset` and find that they compares the underlying integer storage type to improve the `operator<` performance, I test the correctness with following code and get the inconsistent result. Is this a bug?

```
std::vector<bool>       v1, v2;
v1.push_back(0); v1.push_back(1);
v2.push_back(1); v2.push_back(0);
std::cout << (v1 < v2) << '\n';

boost::dynamic_bitset<> b1, b2;
b1.push_back(0); b1.push_back(1);
b2.push_back(1); b2.push_back(0);
std::cout << (b1 < b2) << '\n';
```

I expect the output of both to be `1`, but the second output is `0`.

Comment: @oblivion Where do you see pointers being used in this example?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I was wrong. The comparison operator is defined `template <typename B, typename A> bool operator<(const dynamic_bitset<B, A>& a, const dynamic_bitset<B, A>& b);`

Comment: @康桓瑋 If you're asking about a possible bug in `boost::dynamic_bitset`, you should add the exact version of `boost` and the compiler you use. Post a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: Confirmed output of `1\n0` on boost 1.65.1 on my machine. Same output on 1.62.0 on [this online compiler](https://ideone.com/ravjVo). [The docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#op-less) says it should output `1`, the same as [`operator<` for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the bitset from most significant bits to the least significant ones

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp> 
int main(int, char*[]) {
boost::dynamic_bitset<> x(5); // all 0's by default 
x[0] = 1; 
x[1] = 1; 
x[4] = 1;  
std::cout << x << "\n"; 
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is

```
10011
```

The operator`<<`for `dynamic_bitset` prints the bitset from most-significant to least-significant, since that is the format most people are use to reading.

And this is what you are doing

```
b1.push_back(0); b1.push_back(1);//b1 = 10    
b2.push_back(1); b2.push_back(0);//b2 = 01
```

Boost is correct.
You should change the order of `push_back`s to get what you intended.
[Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)

Comment: Yep, you are right! I see the the document, they say "Effects: Increases the size of the bitset by one, and sets the value of the new most-significant bit to value."

Comment: @康桓瑋 it looks a bit puzzling

Comment: @康桓瑋   bits are commonly numbered from least significant to most significant, so "back" of range is the  most significant bit, that's natural. Bit 0 is 2^0, so its value is 1.